# Using a reverse proxy to combine two sites by putting one under a URL prefix?

Tags: reverse-proxy, varnish

We have an existing web application at www.example.com. The marketing team has a hosted Drupal instance at marketing.example.com. Is there a reverse-proxy solution that would allow me to serve up the marketing content from www.example.com/marketing?

I would like to do this with **networking infrastructure changes only**; ie *NOT* changing either the  marketing site base url configuration, or adding code to www.example.com.

In Varnish, I can do something like:

```
if (req.url ~ "^/marketing/") {
  set req.host = "marketing.example.com";
  set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^/marketing/", "/");
}
```

However, marketing.example.com is serving up HTML with absolute links like "/blog", that now need to be updated to "/marketing/blog". Could the reverse proxy re-write these links, but keep asking the marketing backend for "/blog"?

Again, I don't want to change the configuration of the marketing site to respond to the new URL format itself. I want the reverse proxy to handle all that.

Right now we're using Varnish, but I'm open to other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Varnish can not touch and rewrite the contents being served (only the headers). Maybe the latest and greatest version (3.x) can do it with some VMOD, but I doubt that.

Maybe a setup like the Upside-Down-Ternet (http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pete/upside-down-ternet.html) with squid will help you, what kind of performance are you looking at?